# ARM Create nested Management Group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I try to create an ARM Template for building the ground structure with ManagementGroups
and Subscriptions. My current problem is that I can't  create nested Management Groups,
did somebody already something similiar?

I already have seen this Doc Article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.management/managementgroups?tabs=json

Answer (score 2):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-management-group?tabs=azure-cli#management-group

You need to specify properties.details.parent.id:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('mgName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
        "scope": "/",
        "location": "eastus",
        "properties": {
            "details": {
                "parent": {
                    "id": "[tenantResourceId('Microsoft.Management/managementGroups', parameters('parentMG'))]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
```